# No errors and no file exported. PHP MySQL to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

This is my PHP code, I know the SQL query works, I tested the command to find the new CSV file in the data folder of the database.  However, when I run the query in PHP using MySQL there is no file that appears anywhere. Can please someone point me in the right direction, or tell me where my code is flawed?

```
<?php
  $host="localhost";
  $user="xxxx";
  $password="xxxx";
  $dbname="fbclients";

  $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

  $query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \"contacts10.csv\" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM contacts";
  if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2, $field3);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      //printf("%s, %s\n", $field1, $field2, $field3);
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }
  //$con->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape your quotation marks.

It should be `INTO OUTFILE \"contacts10.csv\"`. Note the backslashes, or use single quotes.

I don't know how this would run without errors. This isn't Perl, here - you can't just have it assume that `contacts10.csv` outside a string means something.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put those back in before I posted.  It doesn't work with the backslashes either, and I wanted to try it without the to see if it would give me an error around that line.  Still nothing.  This is my first script exporting to a file, normally I have just inserted and done a dump in myphpadmin, but I want to give the client access to download their contacts.  My apologies for the mistake in posting.

Comment: @WereGoingLive With that fixed, the file is going into the current working directory of your PHP process. Try giving an absolute path like "/tmp/contacts10.csv".

Comment: @ Borealid, thanks for the quick reply, I'm now getting this **"Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in [PATH] on line 15"**

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Way to this:**

store the query output into the array. And convert the *array to CSV*. It will Working Fine. I will Suggest following code to you.

```
  $host="localhost";
  $user="xxxx";
  $password="xxxx";
  $dbname="fbclients";

  $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());


  $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
  if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  header('Expires: 0');
  $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2, $field3);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    fputcsv($fp, $field1);
    fputcsv($fp, $field2);
    fputcsv($fp, $field3);
    }
    $stmt->close();
  } 

  fclose($fp);
  exit();
```